# Ys Ark of Napishtim - how many levels do the mini-games have?

Tags: ys-6-ark-of-napishtim

In the Sealed Cavern there are a set of mini-games, how many levels do these have each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 initial levels per mini-game, followed by 9 levels after the first 3 levels are completed.